# Force Google Analytics to re-check tracking code status?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

Is there a way to force Google Analytics to re-check tracking code status?

I've just installed the tracking code, but I want Google Analytics to verify whether I installed the code correctly. Google Analitycs's last check was few hours ago, before I installed tracking code.

Current status is "Tracking Not Installed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The displayed status is not important. The Google Analytics snippet on your site will push a pageview to Google Analytics each time the code is executed by a website visitor and since the data only gets updated every few hours, you should see the status change in a few hours (in addition to the tracked pageviews) in your dashboards.

Just stay put and wait a little ...

Comment: okay. i will wait 1 more day and see.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Google Analytics Debugger from the Chrome web store. After it's installed go to the website and press the icon in your chrome toolbar to enable it. The press CTRL+SHIFT+J to enable the console and see debug messages to see if your tracking code is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In every web property in your Google Analytics account, you can see the Tracking Status, which tells you if your tracking code is working or not.

- Sign in to your Analytics account.
- Navigate to the property to which you added the tracking code.
- Click Tracking Info > Tracking Code.
- Review the tracking code status message. Near the tracking ID (UA-XXXXX-XX), you’ll see one of the following status messages:

**Waiting for Data** - The tracking code has been detected on the homepage    of your website, and the Google Analytics servers are updating your    configuration before your data can be processed and appear in your    reports.

**Tracking Not Installed or Not Verified** - The tracking code isn’t set up correctly on your webpages.

**Receiving Data The tracking** - code is collecting and sending data to your property. You can still use the other tools, like the Google Analytics Debugger, to do a more    in-depth analysis or to troubleshoot your setup.

**Unknown** - There's no data available that Google Analytics can use to tell if your tracking    code is working. Check your setup to see if you can find a solution.

**Install and use the Google Analytics Debugger extension (Chrome browser extension) and Use your browser's View Page Source feature to find the tracking code.**

If you use Google Tag Manager to manage Google Analytics tracking, you won't be able to verify that tracking has been installed by viewing the page source. This is because you'll only see a `container snippet`, not the tracking code itself.